# Arc Tweening is snapping as opposed to animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I've been building a pie chart with a sprouting spectrum of arcs.

I've got a demo working, but the arc tweening is snapping as opposed to animating smoothly. Be great if someone can help enhance it so it animates as opposed to snaps the surrounding arcs.

http://jsfiddle.net/BxLHd/9/

I've hard coded the selector threshold. The arcs just don't appear to tween correctly - just seem to snap.

```
var arcGenerator = {
    radius: 100,
    oldData: "",
    init: function(data){
        var clone = jQuery.extend(true, {}, data);
        this.oldData = this.setData(clone, false);
        this.setup(this.setData(data, true));           
    },
    update: function(data){
        var clone = jQuery.extend(true, {}, data);          
        this.animate(this.setData(data, true));         
        this.oldData = this.setData(clone, false);
    },
    animate: function(data){
        var that = this;

        var chart = d3.select(".arcchart");
        that.generateArcs(chart, data);
    },  
    setData: function(data, isSorted){

        var diameter = 2 * Math.PI * this.radius;

        var localData = new Array();

        var innerPieSliceTotal = 0;
        for (x in data) {
            innerPieSliceTotal += data[x].value;
        }

        var displacement = 0;
        var oldBatchLength = 0;

        if(isSorted){
            data.sort(function(a, b) {  
                return b.value - a.value;
            });
        }           

        $.each(data, function(index, value) {               
            var riseLevels = value.riselevels;
            var machineType = value.label;              
            var innerPieSliceValue = value.value;

            var ratioToWorkWith = innerPieSliceValue/innerPieSliceTotal;
            var riseLevelCount = riseLevels.length;

            if(oldBatchLength !=undefined){             
                displacement+=oldBatchLength;
            }

            var arcBatchLength = (2*ratioToWorkWith)*Math.PI;
            var arcPartition = arcBatchLength/riseLevelCount;

                $.each(riseLevels, function( ri, value ) {
                    var startAngle = (ri*arcPartition);
                    var endAngle = ((ri+1)*arcPartition);

                    if(index!=0){
                        startAngle+=displacement;
                        endAngle+=displacement;
                    }

                    riseLevels[ri]["startAngle"] = startAngle;
                    riseLevels[ri]["endAngle"] = endAngle;
                    riseLevels[ri]["machineType"] = machineType;                    
                });

            oldBatchLength = arcBatchLength;

            localData.push(riseLevels);
        });

        var finalArray = new Array();

        $.each(localData, function(index, value) {
            $.each(localData[index], function(i, v) {
                finalArray.push(v);
            });
        });

        return finalArray;

    },
    generateArcs: function(chart, data){

        var that = this;

        //append previous value to it.          
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {               
            data[index]["previousEndAngle"] = that.oldData[index].endAngle; 
        });     

        var arcpaths = chart.selectAll("path")
                .data(data);

            arcpaths.enter().append("svg:path")
                .attr("class", function(d, i){
                    return d.machineType;
                })  
                .style("fill", function(d, i){
                    return d.color;
                })
                .transition()
                .ease("elastic")
                .duration(750)
                .attrTween("d", arcTween);

            arcpaths.transition()
                .ease("elastic")
                .duration(750)
                .attrTween("d",arcTween);

            arcpaths.exit().transition()
                .ease("bounce")
                .duration(750)
                .attrTween("d", arcTween)
                .remove();  

        function arcTween(b) {
            var i = d3.interpolate({value: b.endAngle-0.1}, b);

            return function(t) {
                return that.getArc()(i(t));
            };
        }           
    },
    setup: function(data){      
        var chart = d3.select("#threshold").append("svg:svg")
                .attr("class", "chart")
                .attr("width", 420)
                .attr("height", 420)
                    .append("svg:g")
                    .attr("class", "arcchart")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(200,200)");

        this.generateArcs(chart, data);     
    },
    getArc: function(){
        var that = this;

        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                .innerRadius(that.radius)
                .outerRadius(function(d){
                    var maxHeight = 100;
                    var ratio = (d.height/maxHeight * 100)+that.radius;
                    return ratio;
                })
                .startAngle(function(d, i){
                    return d.startAngle;
                })
                .endAngle(function(d, i){
                    return d.endAngle;
                });

        return arc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your jsfiddle has more than 1200 lines of code. Could you narrow it down to a minimal example please? I'm having a hard time figuring out what is called from where and when.

Comment: Lars, I've compacted the plugin/pie chart code. If you can examine the arcGenerator function http://jsfiddle.net/BxLHd/12/ thank you

Comment: The point of my comment was to get something that's easier to understand. I still have no idea where you're updating that part of the chart -- the update function doesn't seem to select `#threshold` at all.

Comment: Just edited the first post to include the entire object function for the arc generator.

Comment: To clarify -- the problem is not that we don't have the entire code. The problem is figuring out how everything fits together and what is called from where. I suggest that you try to make a minimal example that reproduces the problem (i.e. take away all the code that is not necessary to show it).

Comment: Ok, in its simplest form - is the arc part. http://jsfiddle.net/BxLHd/13/ - if you can relate to the older versions to imagine a doughtnut pie chart tweening/updating in the center. I'd like to ensure the arcs tween smoothly - as oppose to snap.

Answer (score 1):

Your `arcTween` function was interpolating between the wrong values. What you need in this case is an interpolation between the data element with `endAngle` to `previousEndAngle` (as you're already calculating) and the unmodified element. The following code achieves this.

```
 function arcTween(b) {
   var prev = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(b));
   prev.endAngle = b.previousEndAngle;
   var i = d3.interpolate(prev, b);

   return function(t) {
     return that.getArc()(i(t));
   };
 }
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BxLHd/14/).